# Unexpected babel build output

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I get the following output when I transpile a javascript file with Babel 7.

I don't understand the presence of the `cov_5hsavp2s2()` function. It seems to be some metadata.

Is there a way (a flag or config) to prevent it from being generated as it has nothing to do with the functionality of the module.

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = void 0;

var _useMuiTheme = _interopRequireDefault(require("./useRepl"));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function cov_5hsavp2s2() {
  var path = "/home/me/use-repl/src/index.js";
  var hash = "8995b4e9d98ed443cd65fa7d3cf9e2594de820db";
  var global = new Function("return this")();
  var gcv = "__coverage__";
  var coverageData = {
    path: "/home/me/use-repl/src/index.js",
    statementMap: {},
    fnMap: {},
    branchMap: {},
    s: {},
    f: {},
    b: {},
    _coverageSchema: "1a1c01bbd47fc00a2c39e90264f33305004495a9",
    hash: "8995b4e9d98ed443cd65fa7d3cf9e2594de820db"
  };
  var coverage = global[gcv] || (global[gcv] = {});

  if (!coverage[path] || coverage[path].hash !== hash) {
    coverage[path] = coverageData;
  }

  var actualCoverage = coverage[path];
  {
    // @ts-ignore
    cov_5hsavp2s2 = function () {
      return actualCoverage;
    };
  }
  return actualCoverage;
}

cov_5hsavp2s2();
var _default = _useMuiRepl.default;
exports.default = _default;
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@devskope/use-repl",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "files": [
    "/lib"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel --delete-dir-on-start --copy-files src --out-dir lib ",
    "test": "nyc mocha"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "istanbul"
    ]
  },
  "nyc": {
    "require": [
      "@babel/register"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=.10.0.0"
  },
  "author": "devskope",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/devskope/use-mui-theme.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/devskope/use-mui-theme/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/devskope/use-mui-theme#readme",
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "hook",
    "hooks",
    "material-ui",
    "material ui",
    "mui",
    "react",
    "theme"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.4.0",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/register": "^7.10.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "jsdom": "^16.2.2",
    "mocha": "^7.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "nyc": "^15.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your Babel configuration and the relevant Parts of your source Code?

Comment: Are you using `instanbuljs`?

Comment: Yes I have Istanbul  as a dev dependency

Comment: You'll want to separate your babel configuration into its own file so you can include `plugins: ["istanbul"]` and `nyc` only in dev/test.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding an env stanza to the babel config to restrict Istanbul to the test environment.

```
{ //...rest of package.json
    "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "plugins": [
          "istanbul"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
}
```